# Disconnecting signals fails

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

In my code I want to reroute a signal-slot-connection, i.e. first the slot is connected to signal 1, and after the rerouting it should only be connected to signal 2. For that I used `disconnect(this)`, with `this` referring to the class which owns the slots (it is in a class function). This command should disconnect all signals from extern from the class. Unfortunately, I get `false` as return value of `disconnect()`. Why can't I disconnect the signals? Is there a possibility to get more information?
Strangely, in my example below the disconnect and reconnect does not work, too, I get the same error code from `disconnect`.
If I remove the line `connect(this, &MainWindow::writeLine, class1, &TXClass::emit_signal);` from the on_PushButton2_clicked()-function, `disconnect()` still returns "false", but I get the expected result.

Example code:
Mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    class1 = new TXClass("Class 1");
    class2 = new TXClass("Class 2");
    connect(this, SIGNAL(writeLine()), class1, SLOT(emit_signal()));
    connect(class1, SIGNAL(signal(QString)), this, SLOT(newText(QString)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete class1;
    delete class2;
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::newText(QString text)
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText(text);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    emit writeLine();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "Disconnect result: " << disconnect(this);
    connect(this, &MainWindow::writeLine, class2, &TXClass::emit_signal);
    connect(this, &MainWindow::writeLine, class1, &TXClass::emit_signal);
    connect(class2, &TXClass::signal, this, &MainWindow::newText);
    //The onliest signal I want to get now is from class2.
}
```

MainWindow.h:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <txclass.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void writeLine(void);
public slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void newText(QString text);
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    TXClass *class1, *class2;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

TXClass.cpp:

```
#include "txclass.h"

TXClass::TXClass(QString name)
{
    TXClass::name = name;
}


void TXClass::emit_signal()
{
    emit signal(name);
}
```

TXClass.h:

```
#ifndef TXCLASS_H
#define TXCLASS_H
#include <QObject>

class TXClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QString name;
signals:
    void signal(QString string);
public slots:
    void emit_signal(void);
public:
    TXClass(QString name);
};

#endif // TXCLASS_H
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You may check return values of connect to make sure connections are established.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked how `QObject::disconnect` is implemented and I don't see how this is supposed to work if you only specify receiver. [QMetaObjectPrivate::disconnect](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/fd529383c4491580db344fb3d8035bd0ad3cb5e0:src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#L3121) will return immediately with false when sender is not specified. This means that [second part of QObject::disconnect](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/fd529383c4491580db344fb3d8035bd0ad3cb5e0:src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#L2859-3121) will no set `res` to true. The only other place you could get true out of is call to [QInternal::activateCallbacks](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/fd529383c4491580db344fb3d8035bd0ad3cb5e0:src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#L2813-3121). But it [doesn't look](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/fd529383c4491580db344fb3d8035bd0ad3cb5e0:src/corelib/global/qglobal.cpp#L2916) like it's instance specific, rather some global stuff (I admit I have no idea what exactly is this suppose to do :/).

I solution that works and seems good enough is this:

```
void MainWindow::second()
{
    qDebug() << "Disconnect result: " << class1->disconnect();

    connect(this, &MainWindow::writeLine, class2, &TXClass::emit_signal);
    connect(this, &MainWindow::writeLine, class1, &TXClass::emit_signal);
    connect(class2, &TXClass::signal, this, &MainWindow::newText);
    //The onliest signal I want to get now is from class2.
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was it, appearently did I misunderstand how `disconnect` works (and which class should be used as target).